# Increasing the amount of text a notepad style program will take

Tags: .net, forms, character, long-integer

I'm using a simple program that will take tallPDF xml and convert it into a PDF view so you know what your looking at. The problem is I'm limited to how many character I can enter. Is this a problem i can correct in the design view of the form or is the primitive in the code because there is very little code?

AGAIN THIS IS NOT MY CODE. I TAKE NO CREDIT FOR IT!

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // load the XML document template
            System.Xml.XmlDocument documentTemplate = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            documentTemplate.LoadXml(txtPDFXML.Text);

            // Setup the document
            TallComponents.PDF.Layout.Document pdf = new TallComponents.PDF.Layout.Document();
            pdf.Read(documentTemplate.DocumentElement);

            // Finally write the PDF document
            webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
            System.IO.FileStream fs = null;
            try
            {
                fs = new System.IO.FileStream(@"Out.pdf", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
            }
            catch
            {
                fs = new System.IO.FileStream(@"Out2.pdf", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
            }

            pdf.Write(fs, false);
            fs.Close();
            fs.Dispose();

            webBrowser1.Navigate(fs.Name);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the form designer.cs

'partial class Form1
    {
        /// 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// 
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.splitContainer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer();
        this.txtPDFXML = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.webBrowser1 = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer1)).BeginInit();
        this.splitContainer1.Panel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.splitContainer1.Panel2.SuspendLayout();
        this.splitContainer1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // splitContainer1
        // 
        this.splitContainer1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.splitContainer1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.splitContainer1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 4, 4, 4);
        this.splitContainer1.Name = "splitContainer1";
        // 
        // splitContainer1.Panel1
        // 
        this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.txtPDFXML);
        // 
        // splitContainer1.Panel2
        // 
        this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(this.webBrowser1);
        this.splitContainer1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1347, 824);
        this.splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = 693;
        this.splitContainer1.SplitterWidth = 5;
        this.splitContainer1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // txtPDFXML
        // 
        this.txtPDFXML.AcceptsReturn = true;
        this.txtPDFXML.AcceptsTab = true;
        this.txtPDFXML.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.txtPDFXML.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.txtPDFXML.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 4, 4, 4);
        this.txtPDFXML.Multiline = true;
        this.txtPDFXML.Name = "txtPDFXML";
        this.txtPDFXML.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Both;
        this.txtPDFXML.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(693, 824);
        this.txtPDFXML.TabIndex = 0;
        this.txtPDFXML.WordWrap = false;
        // 
        // webBrowser1
        // 
        this.webBrowser1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.webBrowser1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.webBrowser1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 4, 4, 4);
        this.webBrowser1.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(27, 25);
        this.webBrowser1.Name = "webBrowser1";
        this.webBrowser1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(649, 824);
        this.webBrowser1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Bottom;
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 824);
        this.button1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 4, 4, 4);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1347, 28);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.button1.Text = "&View";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1347, 852);
        this.Controls.Add(this.splitContainer1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 4, 4, 4);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.splitContainer1.Panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.splitContainer1.Panel1.PerformLayout();
        this.splitContainer1.Panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer1)).EndInit();
        this.splitContainer1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer splitContainer1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtPDFXML;
    private System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
}
```

}

,

Comment: Would increasing MaxLength help?

Comment: I don't see `MaxLength` mentioned anywhere in the code you provided. Did you forget something ... ?

Comment: What part of this process is limiting you?

Comment: You just posted one part of the Form class - it's a partial class and the designer has generated another part which contains the InitializeComponent() call. My guess is that the interesting part is in there.

Comment: The only thing I have besides the form class is program.cs that just has the main method. Im not sure what to post other that this and maybe form1.cs but that just has form properties.

Comment: MaxLength is in the design view as a property. I don't know if increasing this would allow me to include more characters. To clarify a little, I have a split screen GUI. On one side you write xml and hit a generate button. On the other side the xml is displayed as a pdf. The problem is after about 2 or 3 thousand lines I can't write anymore. Im trying to increase this if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled apon a way to lengthen the characters allowed in this notepad style program. I was going to close the question but META informed me that I should post my answer and accept it so others could use it or add to it, etc. So, after looking around in the code and finding nothing that would help I looked at the UI. This included the notepad style window. I clicked on it and looked at the properties to the right hand side. There is a MaxLength property that was set to 3700 which i set to 9999. This increased the ammount of text I was able to input and solved my problem. Again there may have been other ways to do this but this is what I did and it worked out fine.

Comment: By the way, I consider this just a work around because it doesn't actually require getting into the code so if someone posts an answer that works, I will gladly toggle my answer check off and accept someone elses. Just trying to get the info out there. Thanks.